# Can Bose-Einstein Condensates reflect gravitational waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, gravitational-waves, bose-einstein-condensate

This is a question based on the [paper by Raymond Chiao](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0208024) in 2002 where it is stated:

> One of the conceptual tensions between quantum mechanics (QM) and
>   general relativity (GR) arises from the clash between the spatial
>   nonseparability of entangled states in QM, and the complete spatial
>   separability of all physical systems in GR, i.e., between the
>   nonlocality implied by the superposition principle, and the locality
>   implied by the equivalence principle. Experimental consequences of
>   this conceptual tension will be explored for macroscopically coherent
>   quantum fluids, such as superconductors, superfluids, and atomic
>   Bose-Einstein condensates (BECs), subjected to tidal and
>   Lense-Thirring fields arising from gravitational radiation. A
>   Meissner-like effect is predicted, in which the Lense-Thirring field
>   is expelled from the bulk of a quantum fluid. Superconductors are
>   predicted to be macroscopic quantum gravitational antennas and
>   transducers, which can directly convert upon reflection a beam of
>   quadrupolar electromagnetic radiation into gravitational radiation,
>   and vice versa, and thus serve as both sources and receivers of
>   gravitational waves.

Has there been any followup on this claim, either experimental or theoretical?

Comment: Can graviton condensate?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Chiao

Comment: This is nonsensical. One does not need superconductors etc. to convert gravitational waves into electromagnetic radiation. A couple of charges on a stick will do, but in either case the resulting em emissions will be unmeasurably small. What do you think LIGO does, exactly? It converts a gravitational wave into an electromagnetic signal... in a way that is actually detectable. In other words... we don't need these "results", we have already figured out how to do it right.

Comment: You obviously have not read the paper. For example, in the above the conversion efficiency is claimed to be almost 100%. And simply screaming "nonsensical" is not a critique worth the pixels its written in. Please try harder.